# MVC | Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.common error in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am gettting the below error in MVC

> [A]Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection cannot be cast to [B]Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection. Type A originates from 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common\5.0.414.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll'. Type B originates from 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common\v4.0_6.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidCastException","StackTrace":"   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection.GetConfigurationSourceSection()\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create()\r\n

Please help in resolving the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a version conflict in Enterprise library versions.

You should be able to overcome this issue by adding a [binding redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys(v=vs.110).aspx) to the later version in your `web.config` under `<runtime><assemblyBinding>`:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common" 
                      culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

You may need to redirect any other EntLib assemblies in similar fashion.

Comment: Your suggestion helped me resolved the above error but now i am facing the below issue.

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The configuration section for Exception Handling cannot be found in the configuration source.

Please help !

Comment: This is something totally different - as per the you need to add a `<configSections><section>` for the type in web.config (this is a standard copy paste). Have a google for `enterprise library config section logging`